# Airflow PostgresOperator set ON_ERROR_STOP

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I am creating a task using a PostgresOperator and I would like to set ON_ERROR_STOP=1, is there a way to pass this in the parameter of PostgresOperator or should I put that in my the file "query.sql" directly?

```
my_operator = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='my_operator',
    dag=dag,
    postgres_conn_id='my_server',
    sql="sql/query.sql")
```

For example in bash I can do:

```
psql -v "ON_ERROR_STOP=1"
```

Or is there an easy way to add

```
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on

\unset ON_ERROR_STOP
```

around my query without editing query.sql file ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with postgres but if you can send the `\set ON_ERROR_STOP` and `\unset ON_ERROR_STOP` to postgres just like you'd send any other sql statement you could always do this:

```
my_operator = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='my_operator',
    dag=dag,
    postgres_conn_id='my_server',
    sql=["\set ON_ERROR_STOP on","sql/query.sql", "\unset ON_ERROR_STOP"])
```

With the `dbapi_hook` (which the `postgres_hook` uses) you can send multiple SQL statements through as a list and they all get executed in the same session and in the same order  which they are specified in the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

FYI I'm working with Redshift and this ON_ERROR_STOP was not working but I used instead:

BEGIN;
<my query>
    COMMIT;
END;

that is doing what I was expecting.